# Should I use MSMQ or IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, msmq

I have a web site that exposes a web service to all my desktop clients.

Randomly, these clients will invoke the web service which in turn will add a message jpeg in byte array format to the MSMQ.

I have a service application that reads from this queue and performs an enhancement on this jpeg and saves it to the hard drive.

The number of clients uploading at anyone time is unpredictable.

I choose this method because I do not want to put any strain on IIS.  The enhancements my service application performs is not much 'erg' but it exists nevertheless.

However, after realizing that my service application had stopped for sometime and required restarting I noticed the RAM leap up to clear the backlog. Whilst I have corrected this and the service is now coded to restart automatically on fail I surmised that a backlog could exists at busy times which again give a higher RAM usage.

Now, should I accept to do the processing all within my web service and then save to the hard drive or am I correct in using a MSMQ?

I am using C# and asp.net

Comment: Perhaps I should have not said 'opinions welcome'.  I was actually looking for a factual response and not a preference. Anything to add or is that the level of your input :)

Comment: What's causing the "RAM leap"? How are you measuring this? Working set, for example?